# Simple data Transmission in Boost::asio?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Check these two simple Server Client Program.
As in Condition one. Client is transmitting data to Server and Vies Versa is possible. but when I try to do simultaneously or Consecutively. They are stuck in race condition.

Client program:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

void read(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket1, boost::system::error_code error_code)
{
    boost::asio::streambuf streambuf;
    boost::asio::read(socket1, streambuf, error_code);

    std::istream streambuf1(&streambuf);
    std::string string;
    streambuf1 >> string;
    std::cout << string << std::endl;
}

void write(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket1, boost::system::error_code error_code)
{
    std::string string("hello");
    boost::asio::write(socket1, boost::asio::buffer(string), error_code);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket1(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(socket1.get_io_service());
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), "9999");
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    boost::asio::connect(socket1, iterator);
    boost::system::error_code error_code;

    read(socket1, error_code);
    write(socket1, error_code);
    io_service.run();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is Simple Server Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

void handler(boost::system::error_code &error_code, size_t size)
{
}

void read(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &socket1, boost::system::error_code error_code)
{
    boost::asio::streambuf streambuf;
    boost::asio::read(socket1, streambuf, error_code);

    std::istream streambuf1(&streambuf);
    std::string string;
    streambuf1 >> string;
    std::cout << string << std::endl;
}

void write(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &socket1, boost::system::error_code error_code)
{
    std::string string("hello");
    boost::asio::write(socket1, boost::asio::buffer(string), error_code);
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket1(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service,
                                            boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 9999));
    boost::system::error_code error_code;
    acceptor.accept(socket1, error_code);
    if (error_code != nullptr)
    {
        std::cerr << error_code.message() << std::endl;
    }
    write(socket1, error_code);
    read(socket1, error_code);

    io_service.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Is my way wrong or do i have use boost::asio::async_write() method for transmitting back and forth data.

Comment: What exactly is the problem ? Does it crash ? Does something not work ? `stuck in race condition` When exactly does this happen ? Please provide more information.

Comment: That's the problem. It does not crash. both server and client are not sending data to each other. if I set Simplex Communication (Server to Client || Client to Server ) data is transmitting, but as i used both (Write and Read Function ), nothing happen. neither data is sending nor receiving on both Side. So that the problem.

Comment: Please remember to [accept/upvote an answer if it solved your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the documentation of [`boost::asio::streambuf`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/streambuf.html) you can already spot in the `Examples` section what you possibly do wrong.

First off, your client connects to... what address ? 0.0.0.0 ? You should really specify where it should connect to. *This DOES throw an error,* as you don't handle the error-case on connect. Maybe you did not provide the correct code to reproduce ?

**If you don't want random crashes, handle all possible error cases.**
Boost already helps you with the error out-parameter.

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), "9999"); //0.0.0.0 ?

//---

boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("localhost", "9999"); //Specify where to connect
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
boost::asio::connect(socket1, iterator);
```

So now that you can connect to your remote-partner, you also want to receive the sent message.

```
boost::asio::streambuf streambuf;

//Reserve some bytes for data (here adjusted for your message 'hello')
boost::asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type buf = streambuf.prepare(5); //Refer to documentation
auto sizeReceived = boost::asio::read(socket1, buf, error_code);
//Received bytes are 'committed'
streambuf.commit(sizeReceived);

std::istream streambuf1(&streambuf);
std::string string;
streambuf1 >> string;
std::cout << string << std::endl; //'hello'
```

---

Along with that, this is the full code I have used to test your sample *(don't mind the base-class)*:

```
class Runable
{
public:
    virtual void Run() = 0;
};

class Client : public Runable
{
public:
    void Run() override
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket1(io_service);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(socket1.get_io_service());
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("localhost", "9999"); //Specify where to connect
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
        boost::asio::connect(socket1, iterator);
        boost::system::error_code error_code;

        read(socket1, error_code);
        write(socket1, error_code);
        io_service.run();
    }

private:
    void read(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket1, boost::system::error_code error_code)
    {
        boost::asio::streambuf streambuf;

        boost::asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type buf = streambuf.prepare(5); //Refer to documentation
        auto sizeReceived = boost::asio::read(socket1, buf, error_code);
        streambuf.commit(sizeReceived);

        std::istream streambuf1(&streambuf);
        std::string string;
        streambuf1 >> string;
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " # " << string << std::endl;
    }

    void write(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket1, boost::system::error_code error_code)
    {
        std::string string("hello");
        boost::asio::write(socket1, boost::asio::buffer(string), error_code);
    }
};

class Server : public Runable
{
public:
    void Run() override
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket1(io_service);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service,
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 9999));
        boost::system::error_code error_code;
        acceptor.accept(socket1, error_code);
        if (error_code != nullptr)
        {
            std::cerr << error_code.message() << std::endl;
        }
        write(socket1, error_code);
        read(socket1, error_code);

        io_service.run();
    }

private:
    void read(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &socket1, boost::system::error_code error_code)
    {
        boost::asio::streambuf streambuf;

        boost::asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type buf = streambuf.prepare(5);
        auto sizeReceived = boost::asio::read(socket1, buf, error_code);
        streambuf.commit(sizeReceived);

        std::istream streambuf1(&streambuf);
        std::string string;
        streambuf1 >> string;
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " # " << string << std::endl;
    }

    void write(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &socket1, boost::system::error_code error_code)
    {
        std::string string("hello");
        boost::asio::write(socket1, boost::asio::buffer(string), error_code);
    }
};

int wmain(int argv, wchar_t **args)
{
    std::thread st = std::thread([]() { Server s; s.Run(); });
    std::thread ct = std::thread([]() { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100)); Client c; c.Run(); });

    st.join();
    ct.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Where the output is:

[image: Output]

Please also note, that [`boost::asio::read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read.html) will not return unless the buffer provided is full.

Comment: Note that this is only a fast test. You have to ensure the server is accepting a connection before the call to `connect` on client-side happens. (Here done with a sleep on the current thread)